# What is this extra face that is appearing after extruding?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am following the blender guru youtube tutorial modeling a chair and I'm having this extra face appear even thought it isn't a face or it isn't acting like a face.

Is this normal or is it my settings that make the face appear?

It happens everytime I extrude the vertices and always get this fake face on it.

I'm new to blender and I am barely starting out.

[image]

Comment: Where is the face you are talking about? can you circle it in the screenshot (you can use paint or similar)

Comment: Some kind of a prank post?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are seeing the difference between your Modifier and the actual bounds of the mesh.  Try toggling the "Display Modifier in Edit Mode" button.

[image]